# Stack implimentation using Linkedlist in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list

I have written a code in C language to implement a stack using LinkedList algorithm. Here is the code........

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>
struct listNode {
int data;
struct listNode *next;
};
struct stack{
struct stack *top;
};
struct stack *createstk(){
    struct stack *stk;
    stk=malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    stk->top=NULL;
    return stk;
}
void push(struct stack *stk,int data){
    struct listNode *temp;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct listNode));
    if(!temp){
        printf("heap overflow");
        return;
    }
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=stk->top;
    stk->top=temp;
}
int pop(struct stack *stk){
    if(isEmpty(stk))
        return INT_MIN;
    int data;
    struct listNode *temp;
    temp= stk->top;
    stk->top=stk->top->next;
    data=temp->data;
    delete(temp);
    return data;
}
int peek(struct stack *stk){
    if(isEmpty(stk))
        return INT_MIN;
    return stk->top->data;
}
int isEmpty(struct stack *stk){
    return stk->top==NULL;
}
void deleteStack(struct stack *stk){
    struct listNode *temp,*p;
    p=stk->top;
    while(p){
        temp=p->next;
        p=p->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    free(stk);
}
int main(){
    int i=0;
    struct stack *stk=createstk();
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
        push(stk,i);
    printf("Top Element is %d",peek(stk));
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
        printf("popped element is %d",pop(stk));
    }
    if(isEmpty(stk))
        printf("stack is empty");
    else
        printf("stack is not empty");
    deleteStack(stk);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: It is generate such errors like:]

> [warning]assignment from incompatible pointer type.
>   As you can see above in the picture. I am a newbie in coding world and facing this error first time. That's why I don't know what to do. Please tell me...

Comment: `struct listNode *temp;` creates `temp` as a pointer to `listNode` (`temp->next` is the same). You attempt `temp->next=stk->top;` which attempts to assign `stk->top` (type pointer to `struct stack`). You can't assign a pointer to `struct stack` to a pointer to `listNode`. (you have similar error throughout)

Comment: temp->next points to a different type than stk->top

Answer (score 0):

The field *top* in the type *stack* has the wrong type. Change

```
struct stack {
    struct stack *top;
};
```

to

```
struct stack {
    struct listNode *top;
};
```

Comment: That is a start, but that won't fix it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But it answers the question.

Comment: Yes, that is a true statement. But generally when someone is struggling with a type issue, providing an answer to the type problem alone where many others exist, just moves him to the next error and he is stuck again. Your answer is fine, and I give you credit in the one I posted for it, but I always try and step into the role of teacher and help the student though the remaining issues. Nothing wrong with either approach.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agreed, though it's also good to learn to struggle.

Answer (score 0):

Your have a large number of error beginning with the incorrect type for `stack->top`, as correctly noted by [August Karlstrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337149/august-karlstrom) your type for the member `top` must be `struct listNode *top;`, e.g.

```
struct stack {
    struct listNode *top;
};
```

Following the correction, you must either reorder your functions or provide function prototypes for `isEmpty()` and `deleteStack()`. Moving them up in your code before before their first use will solve the problem, e.g.

```
struct stack *createstk()
{
    struct stack *stk;
    stk = malloc (sizeof (struct stack));
    stk->top = NULL;
    return stk;
}

int isEmpty (struct stack *stk)
{
    return stk->top == NULL;
}

void deleteStack (struct stack *stk)
{
    struct listNode *temp, *p;
    p = stk->top;
    while (p) {
        temp = p->next;
        p = p->next;
        free (temp);
    }
    free (stk);
}
...
```

Next, this is C, not C++ there is no `delete` function to free memory, so in `pop()`, you must call `free (temp);` instead of `delete (temp);`.

Finally, provide spacing to make your code readable. Incorporating the above, you could do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct listNode {
    int data;
    struct listNode *next;
};

struct stack {
    struct listNode *top;
};

struct stack *createstk()
{
    struct stack *stk;
    stk = malloc (sizeof (struct stack));
    stk->top = NULL;
    return stk;
}

int isEmpty (struct stack *stk)
{
    return stk->top == NULL;
}

void deleteStack (struct stack *stk)
{
    struct listNode *temp, *p;
    p = stk->top;
    while (p) {
        temp = p->next;
        p = p->next;
        free (temp);
    }
    free (stk);
}

void push (struct stack *stk, int data){

    struct listNode *temp;

    temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
    if (!temp) {
        perror ("push()-malloc-temp");
        return;
    }

    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = stk->top;
    stk->top = temp;
}

int pop(struct stack *stk){

    int data;
    struct listNode *temp;

    if (isEmpty(stk))
        return INT_MIN;

    temp = stk->top;
    data = temp->data;
    stk->top = stk->top->next;

    free (temp);

    return data;
}
int peek(struct stack *stk){
    if(isEmpty(stk))
        return INT_MIN;
    return stk->top->data;
}

int main (void) {
    int i=0;
    struct stack *stk=createstk();

    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        push(stk,i);

    printf("Top Element is %d\n",peek(stk));

    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        printf ("  popped element is %d\n",pop(stk));

    if (isEmpty(stk))
        printf ("stack is empty\n");
    else
        printf ("stack is not empty\n");

    deleteStack(stk);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stack_ll
Top Element is 10
  popped element is 10
  popped element is 9
  popped element is 8
  popped element is 7
  popped element is 6
  popped element is 5
  popped element is 4
  popped element is 3
  popped element is 2
  popped element is 1
  popped element is 0
stack is empty
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/stack_ll
==25935== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25935== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25935== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25935== Command: ./bin/stack_ll
==25935==
Top Element is 10
  popped element is 10
  popped element is 9
  popped element is 8
  popped element is 7
  popped element is 6
  popped element is 5
  popped element is 4
  popped element is 3
  popped element is 2
  popped element is 1
  popped element is 0
stack is empty
==25935==
==25935== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25935==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25935==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 12 frees, 184 bytes allocated
==25935==
==25935== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25935==
==25935== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25935== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

If you have any further questions, just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. I had asked about this problem to my college professor but he ignored me. So,  I posted the problem in the community. It's work. I have some confusion regarding pointers. So, can you please help me with that or suggest me some online source or anything you can? I need to clear my concept as I'm not getting any help from my sirs. and Thanks again.

Comment: @B.Sarkar read the answer to [Obtaining address of pointer in C with and without ampersand, what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568116/obtaining-address-of-pointer-in-c-with-and-without-ampersand-whats-the-differe/53568400?r=SearchResults&s=3|53.3125#53568400) and let me know if you still have questions. A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the memory address where something else is stored.