# two functions (read and display an array) using pointers to structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I just start to learn pointers to structures and I'm confused.I have to create a type of data ARRAY (which is associated with an array which contains integers.) like a structure which contains: numbers of array's elements and the array's elements stored in a part of memory(heap), dynamically allocated.

So I wrote:

```
typedef struct ARRAY
{
        int nrElem; // number of elements
        int *v[100];
};
```

Now I need to create 2 functions, one for reading an array from keyboard and the second one to display it using the structure I declared.

I tried but I get stuck.

```
void arrayDisplay(ARRAY *ps)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<pd->nrElem;++i)
        {
                printf("%d",)
        }
}

void readArray(ARRAY *ps)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<pd->nrElem;++i)
        {
                printf("%d",)
                scanf("%d",&);
        }
}
```

How to continue?

Comment: What is the exact problem you have? What do you want to achieve? Make a small test in the function main() to show that it does or doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @DaniVajaWhat is this  int int *v[100];?

Comment: That's the problem.The sentence is what I wrote in first paragraph.From there I need to create different function using pointers to structures like display an array, read an array, scalar product of 2 arrays, sort 2 arrays etc.I just want to know how to work with that struct.

Comment: Well, this part I didn;t totally understand " the array's elements stored in a part of memory(heap)" which is the second member of the struct. So that is an array which contains pointers to int.My mistake, just int *v[100];

Comment: When working with pointers you need to know how to allocate and deallocate the memory addressed by a pointer. Please, study it.

Comment: Read more about them. None of this code has any chance in compiling, and most of the issues have nothing to do with pointers or structures. They're far more fundamental than that. (broken `printf` calls, incorrect variable names, being obvious). Figure out how to read a fixed array *first* (a simple `main` program that populates an array of `int` from user input). Once you know how to do that, *then* take this on.

Comment: I know how to read an array without this.That printf and scanf I left them in this way because I didn't know if what to put there.I usually write printf("a(%d)=", i); scanf("%d", &a[i]);

Comment: You may find [Obtaining address of pointer in C with and without ampersand, what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568116/obtaining-address-of-pointer-in-c-with-and-without-ampersand-whats-the-differe/53568400?r=SearchResults&s=4|43.7154#53568400) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array of pointers `int *v[100];` you need an array of ints `int v[100];` in your data structure.

See code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ARRAY
{
        int nrElem; // number of elements
        int v[100];
} ARRAY;

void arrayDisplay(ARRAY *ps)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<ps->nrElem;++i)
        {
                printf("%d\n", ps->v[i]);
        }
}

void readArray(ARRAY *ps)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<ps->nrElem;++i)
        {
                printf("%d: ", i);
                scanf("%d",&ps->v[i]);
        }
}

int main()
{
    ARRAY a;

    a.nrElem = 5;
    readArray(&a);
    arrayDisplay(&a);

    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to use an array of int pointers you need to allocate the array first. And a different level of redirection for printf and scanf. But I'm not sure why you want to allocate memory for an integer array like this.

```
typedef struct ARRAY
{
        int nrElem; // number of elements
        int *v[100];
} ARRAY;

void arrayDisplay(ARRAY *ps)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<ps->nrElem;++i)
        {
                printf("%d\n", *ps->v[i]);
        }
}

void readArray(ARRAY *ps)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<ps->nrElem;++i)
        {
                printf("%d: ", i);
                scanf("%d",ps->v[i]);
        }
}

int main()
{
    ARRAY a;
    int i;

    a.nrElem = 5;
    for(i=0;i<a.nrElem;++i) {
        a.v[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(a.v[i]));
    }
    readArray(&a);
    arrayDisplay(&a);

    return 0;
}
```