# why a variable of linked list must be a pointer

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have a code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
}node;

int main(){
    node *a;
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone explain to me why **a** must be a pointer but not a variable type node? tks for your help

Comment: Who/where does it say it has to be a pointer? There is no such rule. It depends on the context of the code.

Comment: @kaylum can you tell me in which context we use pointers and in which context we use regular variables please?

Comment: A pointer is just a normal variable that holds the address to something else as its value.  You can declare a struct and storage will be reserved on the stack You can access the struct through the declared variable or assign its address to a pointer. With a linked list, the memory isn't normally declared on the stack, but generally you allocate storage in memory for each node. You assign the address where the node lives in memory to a pointer. You can also use a pointer to iterate over the nodes (e.g. `struct *p = node; while (p != NULL) { p = p->next; }`) which is another common list use.

Comment: [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) compare with [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) which provides both a `head` pointer (pointer to 1st node in list) and a `tail` pointer (pointer to last node in list) to avoid having to iterate to insert the next node at the end.

Comment: For a quick pointer intro [Obtaining address of pointer in C with and without ampersand, what's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568116/obtaining-address-of-pointer-in-c-with-and-without-ampersand-whats-the-differe/53568400?r=SearchResults&s=4|43.7154#53568400)

Answer (score 2):

The next node of a linked list is given by `struct node *next;`

This, by definition has to be a pointer. You cannot have a variable of `struct node` inside another variable of `struct node`

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node next;   //-- Not Allowed
}node;
```

The above declaration will not compile as the size of a `struct node` will be infinite.

It is possible for the **head** of the linked list to be a non pointer, but this unnecessarily complicates the code as you need to have two code segments seperately for head and for other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

In "C" parameter passing is done by value. To allow a called function to make changes to the data structure, or to stay synchronized with future changes to the data structure, functions are passed a pointer to the object.

Long Answer:
Consider a caller, and a callee functions where the callee has to change the first element on the linked list. Since callee will be passed a COPY of the linked-list head node, the changes it makes to the head->next are done on the copy. The "caller" function 'head1' is not modified, when `callee` return, the change (and the malloc) are lost.

```
void callee(struct node head)
{
    struct node new_node = malloc(...)
    new_node = head.next ;
    head->next = new_node ;
}

void called(void) {
    struct node head1 = ...
    callee(head1) ;
} ;
```

As a side note, for the following cases, it is technically possible to use a 'struct node' to represent the linked-list (to the callee). However, here are some arguments against having two representations in the same code, and remembering which one to use is `recipe for disaster`

- The linked-list `head` item is not modified by the callee.
- If the callee store the linked-list for future call (e.g., static variable), the link list can not be modified.

**My personal advise, ALWAYS USE POINTERS**

Answer (score 0):

In C linked list is used as a dynamic array. Unlike normal array in C it doesn't have to be of specific size and it can keep expanding or decreasing upon need.

As the struct node has 2 data members :

1.the data it stores (int value)

2.the address of next location (*next)

so for linked list to work we declare "a" as a pointer so that with only be one variable
that we can use to traverse through the whole list . We can simply make "a" point towards the next element in the list so that we can access it. 
We can use a base element which i am assuming is

```
   struct node node;
```

so that we can make a point towards it to get to the start of the list as it is single linked list.