# Representing a Data instance as a pointer in a C++ linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Suppose we are a vehicle manufacturer, and we have an abstract `Part` class that looks like the following:

```cpp
class Part {
    // notice that that all methods are const methods.
public:
    Part():itsPartNumber(1) {}
    Part(int PartNumber):itsPartNumber(PartNumber) {}
    virtual ~Part() {};
    int GetPartNumber() const { return itsPartNumber; }
    virtual void Display() const = 0;
private:
    int itsPartNumber;
};
```

This will be our Data class in the linked list where the node looks like this.

```cpp
class PartNode
{
public:
    PartNode(Part*); 
    ~PartNode();
    void setNext(PartNode* node) { itsNext = node; }
    Part* GetPart() const;
    PartNode* GetNext() const;
private: 
    Part* itsPart;
    PartNode* itsNext;
};
```

Now my question is, we can't really manipulate `Part` instances as all the methods are const. Therefore, does it matter if we change all `Part*` to just `Part`? Or should the data itself be a pointer in the linked list?

P.S:
I don't think this is a duplicate of [Variable as pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367884/why-a-variable-of-linked-list-must-be-a-pointer) as it was talking about `next` which of course, has to be a pointer.

Any explanation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it will certainly matter if you change all your `Part *`s to `Part`. Your suffering C++ compiler will completely refuse to compile the shown code. I suspect that you expect objects in C++ to work like they do in Java or C#. C++ is not Java or C#.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik , do you have an idea about why it will suffer?

Comment: Well, of course I do, since I asserted that as factual I must believe this to be the case. Just try it yourself. Or, take any class in C++, add an abstract method, and try to make it a member of another class, instead of a pointer. It won't work. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OHHH I forgot Part was an abstract class with a purely virtual method. Silly me!

Comment: Might be fine.  Might not be.  If `Part` has value semantics and no identity, probably will be fine.  Have you applied the age old technique of FA&FO ("try it, and find out") yet?  You will have the opportunity to learn about *object slicing*, which is a valuable lesson to learn.

Comment: @Eljay It may have been best to make a new example as either way, Part is ADT so I have to use a pointer

Comment: There you go, you have answered your own question.  When *any* of a set of polymorphic objects are passed around (or referred to), they **must** be passed around by reference or pointer — otherwise *object slicing*.  An ADT **cannot** be instantiated.

Comment: "Part instances as all the methods are const. Therefore, does it matter if we change all Part* to just Part?" This is a non sequitur. Being effectively const and being accessed through a pointer are two independent qualities. One has nothing to do with the other.

Answer (score 2):

> Now my question is, we can't really manipulate Part instances as all the methods are const.

There are no `Part` instances. `Part` is purely abstract (i.e. an `Interface` in various other languages).

```
virtual void Display() const = 0;
```

You cannot instantiate an `Interface`.

> Therefore, does it matter if we change all `Part*` to just `Part`?

Well *firstly* yes. You cannot use a pure abstract `class` as a member variable in another `class` because when the `class` is instantiated, it means that the pure abstract `class` will be instantiated also. The compiler will not allow that.

> …we can't really manipulate `Part` instances as all the methods are `const`. Therefore, does it matter if we change all `Part*` to just `Part`?

Pointer or not, only *non*-`const` methods can *manipulate* members of object instances. Unless the members are themselves declared [`mutable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv#mutable_specifier)<sup>[1]</sup>, `const` methods cannot *manipulate* them.

---

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> *Only consider mutable for the "M&M rule".*</sub>